# PHP Insert Into won't work

Tags: php, mysql

I have this register form that I like all my data to be sent to my mysql server using php. Here's my code:

```
$gidnumber = htmlentities($_POST['stud_idnumber']);
$gfirstname = htmlentities($_POST['stud_firstname']);
$glastname = htmlentities($_POST['stud_lastname']);
$gcourse = htmlentities($_POST['stud_course']);
$gyear = htmlentities($_POST['stud_year']);
$gpassword = htmlentities($_POST['stud_password']);
```

For security reasons, I tried doubling up by using `real_escape_string`

```
$stud_idnumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$gidnumber);
$stud_firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$gfirstname);
$stud_lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$glastname);
$stud_course = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$gcourse);
$stud_year = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$gyear);
$stud_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$gpassword);
```

Followed by a:

```
$sql3 = "INSERT INTO users_student 
                (idnumber, firstname, lastname, course, year, password) 
         VALUES "." ('$stud_idnumber','$stud_firstname','$stud_lastname',
                     '$stud_course','$stud_year','$stud_password') ";
$q = mysqli_query($con,$sql3);

echo "<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>";
echo $stud_idnumber;
echo $stud_firstname;
echo $stud_lastname;
echo $stud_course;
echo $stud_year;
echo $stud_password;
```

The `echo` part was for checking if the php really gets all the variables in the textboxes. On my page, it successfully displayed all the user has input in the textbox (firstname, lastname, etc...). But when I checked my database, it didn't saved it there.
Also it was not giving me any errors.

Comment: Your passwords are at risk without encryption. You should look into using password_hash and password_verify.

Comment: why are you escaping passwords?

Comment: @Option Oh! how could I do that?? I'm so sorry for being naive, I thought `htmlentities` was enough though

Comment: @Dranreb, take a look at the php.net site for password hashing: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Comment: NEVER use htmlentities when inserting into database

Comment: @131 Oh! Why not?

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you cannot miss or ignore.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: `"." ` in the middle of the query? **Why**

Comment: cause if someone uses html tags in their password, ex. `password13<`, the `htmlentities()` will convert it to `password12&lt;` because it escapes those characters. You only use it before you output data to the browser.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks! It give out an error like this: ` Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'' in C:\xampp\htdocs\buksunetwork\welcome.php:70 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\buksunetwork\welcome.php(70): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'INSERT INTO use...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\buksunetwork\welcome.php on line 70` any ideas about this?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Line 70: `mysqli_query($con,$sql3);`

Comment: So the column either does not exist in that table or it has a different name

Comment: It does seem a little off that you would store a password in a table with that name??? Password should go in the `user` table

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks! I found out the `password` field in my table didn't exist. That was really stupid of me to miss that out. Thank you once again! :)